# present transparent modal view in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

there are lots of answers but none seems to be working normally/perfectly for iOS 9 specifically 9.2.. Someone help with it please. Its a simple scenario where:

1) Storyboard segues are connected to a single toBePresentedModally View Controller, i chose UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext as well as switched and tried with UIModalPresentationCurrentContext when style from storyboard wasn't working.

2) i either get a black background after 1 second of happiness (it works fine for just a second) OR i get a blank controller when trying to present it through code by allocating a class of toBePresentedModally View Controller.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 2):

This is how, I have done in my code

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard.loadViewController("Identifier")
viewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
viewController.definesPresentationContext = true
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
self.presentViewController(viewController)
```

And it is working fine.

Comment: not looking for Swift implementation! thanx though!

Comment: It is not difficult to convert swift into objective c, If you say I can do that for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer, tested in iOS 9+:

Using storyboard

Select your segue and in property inspector:

- **Kind "Modal"**
- **Presentation and Transition "Default"**

[image]

After, select your modal view controller and in property inspector:

- **Presentation "Over current context"**

[image]

Hope can help you man.

Answer (score 0):

implement the class 'TransitionDelegate' which conforms to the protocol UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and give implementation for

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    AnimatedTransitioning *controller = [[AnimatedTransitioning alloc]init];
    controller.isPresenting = YES;
    return controller;
}
```

Your AnimatedTransition class should look this,

```
#import "AnimatedTransitioning.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation AnimatedTransitioning

//===================================================================
// - UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
//===================================================================

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.25f;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIView *inView = [transitionContext containerView];
    SecondViewController *toVC = (SecondViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    MainViewController *fromVC = (MainViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    [inView addSubview:toVC.view];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [toVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenRect.size.height, fromVC.view.frame.size.width, fromVC.view.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                     animations:^{

                         [toVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fromVC.view.frame.size.width, fromVC.view.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                     }];
}
@end
```

Here i am giving implementation for a button action in source view controller class(MainViewController.m), i hope you can change it as per your requirements,

```
- (IBAction)displaySecondVC:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    vc.modalPresentationStyle= UIModalPresentationCustom;
    [vc setTransitioningDelegate:transitionController];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in viewdidLoad of the same class add this

```
self.transitionController = [[TransitionDelegate alloc] init];
```

Reach me for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a transparent background for your ViewController try this!!

- Take a View (named as **DimmedView**) and make it Equal width and Height to the superView.
- Set SuperView's Background Color as **ClearColor** and DimmedView's **LightGrayColor** with **alpha 0.5**
- Now take a CenterView with your actual content and set proper constraints.
- Add **Tap gesture to the DimmeedView** if you want to dismiss Controller on touch outside of your CenterView.
- Now when you present viewController set this property.

  ```
  ViewController *VC = segue.destinationViewController;
  VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
  ```
- Don't forget to dissmiss ViewController on TapGesture Event.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DashboardSettingsViewController *view=[self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashboardSettings"];

view.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
view.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[view setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction =
[CAMediaTimingFunction   functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;


//// for a smoother navigation
UIView *containerView = self.view.window;
[containerView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];

// lastly the background of to be presented view controller should be set to clear with alpha of your choice!
```